when we put a "const" in front of a function definition?
I did not find any difference if I have a const in front of a function definition or not.
template<typename T>
class coor {
private:    
    T x;
    T y;
public:
    auto X()const { return x; }
    auto Y()const { return y; }
    coor() :x(0), y(0) {}
    coor(T a=0, T b=0):x(a), y(b){}
    const coor(const coor& P) {  // copy constructor. W/O the first const it makes no difference.
        x = P.X();
        y = P.Y();
    }
    const coor operator+ (const coor& P) {   //first const, necessary or not?
         coor ans(x + P.x, y + P.y);
       return ans;
    }
    ~coor(){}
    const coor addone() {    // const, necessary or not?
        x++;
        y++;
        return *this;
    }
};
int main()
{
    coor<int> p1(1, 1);
    coor<int> p2(2, 2);
    coor<int> p3(p1);
    p3 = p2;
    coor<int> p = p1 + p2;
    coor<int> p4 = p.addone();
    return 0;
}


I have 3 functions in the class definition. And I found no matter I have const or not it will work.
One is copy constructor. Second is operator overloading. Third one is a normal function.

returning a const object by value is pointless.

If you add auto X() { return x; }, it will still work. Is that what you want to see?

const int i = 10; int j; j = i; Having the i be const does not prevent j from being assigned the value of i.

GCC fails to compile your example with: 11:16: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’.

I think the only place where const is needed is auto X()const and auto Y()const. These allow the methods to be called on const instances because they don't modify the object.

addone() seems strange. It modifies the object in place, and also returns a copy of it. Why do both?

"const in front a function" is attributed not the function itself, but to its return type. const a foo() means that foo() returns const a.

@NathanOliver almost pointless.  In this case it is. There might be some hypotetical type which would have limits what can be done to it (e.g. having a non-public copy), and const value would also be non-movable

CV and reference qualifiers at the end of a member function declarations, belong to *this object. They limit the manipulations to *this. Make sure you fully understand what CV qualifiers mean and do, before you proceed with anything.

The program is ill-formed because we're not allowed to put const before a copy ctor.
MSVC is wrong to accept the program without any diasnostic. Both gcc and clang correctly rejects the program.
Demo
template<typename T>
class coor {
private:    
    T x;
    T y;
public:
//--vvvvv----------------------->this is invalid 
    const coor(const coor& P) 
    {   
    } 
};


Short answer In your specific case, It is not necessary. according to GCC x86-64 Compiler 14.1.
I had to do some rework on the code for specially the copy constructor to remove the compilation error.
coor(const coor & P) {  // copy constructor. shouldn't be const
    x = P.X();
    y = P.Y();
}

This function should be translated into the same assembly code with the specified compiler.
const coor addone() {    // no difference
    x++;
    y++;
    return *this;
}

Here is the assembly code if you wish to look at
coor<int>::addone():
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 16
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rsi
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
    lea     edx, [rax+1]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax+4]
    lea     edx, [rax+1]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     DWORD PTR [rax+4], edx
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     rsi, rdx
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    coor<int>::coor(coor<int> const&) [complete object constructor]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    leave
    ret

Note that, This is because the const return value will return an object which in this case is const but when assigned to a variable inside the main function, const keyword should not take effect because you are assigning the const object to a newly created object with value. that is why the compiler optimizes it.
In other cases, where pointers are involved, There must be specific handling of the return value from the function
for example this code won't compile
const int *y(int a)
{
    return &a;
}
int main()
{
   int m = 5;
   int *z =  y(5); // should be changed to const int *z
}


One should answer a c++ question by trying to compare it with the generated assembly. Instead it should be answered from the perspective of the c++ standard. Also this answer looks more like trial and error to get the right answer.

C++ is, with no doubt, a machine language that we should look at it from its assembly generated code. It is major in c and c++ to look at how they will be executed on the hardware.

"we should look at it from its assembly generated cod..." No, that is not the way to learn/study c++.  Instead a good c++ book and the c++ standard should be used. The generated code has nothing to do with whether the code is well-formed or not. Even a program with undefined behavior produces generated code. Your statement is like saying one should learn python from the generated byte code.

I agree, not in all cases we should look at assembly code. But the question was about a keyword like "const" will take effect or not, this should be easily inspected by looking at the assembly code.. Also, I added a clarification on when the const must and is necessary to be used. Also, it seems that const in this  case is ambiguous as you are returning object by value which which can be interpreted as const value assigned to a non const variable. so you can assign it to any local object

Again inspection is not the same as proof. You can inspect things different based on different compilers, factors. The question is c++ tagged and not assembly tagged and needs a c++ answer.

OP doesn't understand what const means at the grammar level and you suggest that they look at the assembly code? It's like asking the one who learns how to drive a car to take a look at differential equations for air flow around that car...

In the cases of
const coor operator+ (const coor& P);
const coor addone();

you're declaring each of these functions to have the return type const coor. This is valid, but rarely done. It means that for example the result of the call p.addone() is a prvalue of const-qualified type. This may stop the caller from accidentally calling a method on p.addone() that would further modify the prvalue's result object. However, it also stops the caller from intentionally modifying the result of p.addone(). For example, let's say there's some other function:
void foo(coor&&);

The call foo(p.addone()) won't compile because coor&& won't bind to the const coor object returned from addone. Making addone return a const object can prevent legitimate usage of the object that involves modifying it, such as passing it to the function foo which may need to move from it.
Therefore, generally speaking, functions should not be declared to return const objects by value.
The case of the copy constructor is a bit different:
const coor(const coor& P);

In this case coor is the name used to declare coor's constructor, and const stands alone as a decl-specifier, instead of having another type to modify. A constructor is not permitted to have const as one of its decl-specifiers ([class.ctor.general]/1) so the program is ill-formed (and it is a bit surprising that your compiler accepts it).
